# Travis-CI python3.6 Tox launching virtualenv error

Tags: python, virtualenv, travis-ci, tox

We are using `tox` for py36 test environment setup through `travis-ci`, the tests start breaking in 2021-10-23.

The error that we are getting is:

```
$ tox
GLOB sdist-make: /home/travis/build/apache/incubator-marvin/python-toolbox/setup.py
py36 create: /home/travis/build/apache/incubator-marvin/python-toolbox/.tox/py36
ERROR: invocation failed (exit code 1), logfile: /home/travis/build/apache/incubator-marvin/python-toolbox/.tox/py36/log/py36-0.log
================================== log start ===================================
StopIteration: 
=================================== log end ====================================
ERROR: InvocationError for command /home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.7/bin/python -m virtualenv --no-download --python /home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.7/bin/python py36 (exited with code 1)
___________________________________ summary ____________________________________
ERROR:   py36: InvocationError for command /home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.7/bin/python -m virtualenv --no-download --python /home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.7/bin/python py36 (exited with code 1)
The command "tox" exited with 1.
```

[Full Log Travis-CI Link](https://app.travis-ci.com/github/apache/incubator-marvin/jobs/549545377)

The log showed that the process had failed while launching `virtualenv` even before package installation.

We had also tested with `tox -rvve py36` for more logs:

[Another log with Travis-CI Link](https://app.travis-ci.com/github/apache/incubator-marvin/jobs/549619263)

The test result showed that `/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.7/bin/python` does exist, and can be successfully executed.

What is weird to us is that the same setting used to be able to run without failure in 2021-10-22:

[Previous log with Travis-CI Link](https://app.travis-ci.com/github/apache/incubator-marvin/jobs/544594850)

And the only difference seem to be the version change of `virtualenv`, which is changing from `20.8.1` to `20.9.0` or `20.10.0`.

Does anyone know how this can be fixed?

Comment: This looks like a bug and therefore should go on the tox issue tracker, not on SO. One of the tox maintainers is also the virtualenv maintainers 

Comment: Ok, I just report it here: https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/2280
I will also post the result onto SO when there is a solution.

Comment: Issue moved to discussion: https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/discussions/2286

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experiments, we found that there are many dependencies that could be the cause of this error.

For our case, it is the OpenSSL version in the Ubuntu.

https://github.com/apache/incubator-marvin/pull/59